# Microsoft Outlook shows that email was received, but actually it was sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, usability

Microsoft Outlook shows that email was received, but actually it was sent:

[image]

Why? Is it a bug?

UPD. I did not *receive* this email. I *sent* this email. On my side this email cannot be *received*. It can be only *sent*.

Comment: It was “received” in the sent items folder at that time. What you describe is NOT a bug.

Comment: @Ramhound while true, there is a bit of a bug going on. The received column is valid of cource, but should be hidden by the Sent Items view. You can see this because the FROM column is also visible, which should be hidden too. Instead the To should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an email is sent to someone, it will contain a lot of information. Date received, date sent, From, To, Subject, Bytes, Location, etc...

Judging from the screenshot, you are seeing emails in your Sent Items folder, but with the wrong view selected. Normally, the view you are showing is for incoming emails. Outlook normally switches to a different view showing all the useful columns for sending emails, not receiving. In your screenshot, you see the FROM column, which is completely useless in the sent items view because it would put your name everywhere, not the person you sent the email to. It should also not show the received column, but sent on column.

The received column will in this case show the date the email was sent as that was the time the email item was created in your Sent Items folder, and for outlook, it doesn't matter if it was outlook who created it, or the email got created as part of a download from your mailserver.

Now, the only reason I can think of why this happens to you, is that you performed a search, in which case it is valid to show the received view, and not the sent view.

Comment: Does it mean that "From" and "Received" shall contain "N/A"?

Comment: No, it means they will contain information, its just not relative because you can guess these as you actually sent the email. Received is going to be the same as Sent on, and From is you, To is to whoever you sent it to.

Comment: Should non-relative information be hidden? Otherwise it may confuse the end users.

Comment: It is normally. But because the screenshot shows the word "Results", I have a feeling this is a search result, in which case this is normal because most results will not come from the sent items, and then all information matters.

Comment: Yes, it is a search result.

Comment: Hi @pmor, I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description and the screenshot you provide, I notice that you have added a column "In folder" in View setting and the search result is shown. As I know, since the default view displays the "Received" column, when you switch to a different folder, the views are fixed. In fact, the time displayed in the "Received" column of the email in the "Send Items" folder is the time when the email was sent.

If you don't want such a display, just select the "Send Items" folder, **remove the "received" column in the view settings, and add the "sent" column.** For specific steps, please refer to:

1.Select "Sent Items" folder;

2.**View**>**View Settings**>**Columns…**

[image]

3.Remove the **"Received"** column;

[image]

4.Add the "**Sent"** column;

[image]

5.Click **OK**>**OK**.

Then when the search result in Sent Items folder will just display the "Sent" column, which shows the time of the sent emails. Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.